# Binding JQuery events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, binding

JQuery events are annoying me. The thing is that I very often use 
javascript (after ajax requests, etc.) to draw up new elements 
(buttons, divs, etc.). I've got a list of elements 
which you can press on an edit button so you can manipulate the one 
linked to the selected edit button.

Now if someone submits a form to make a new element like the ones who 
existed before, and I submit it with ajax and then I append or prepend 
the new element into the list. After that the new edit button for the 
new element isn't linked to JQuery's event system since the DOM hasn't 
been reloaded after the edit button was made. If I call the same 
javascript file with the events in it, then the edit button works but 
then when people click other edit buttons the event happens twice for 
them since they're bound twice. I've also used .bind() but that only 
binds (I think) the same event twice as before. I don't remember at 
the moment how I tested it. I haven't tested .one() but I would rather 
not use it since some events must be called more than once.

I just wanted to ask you guys what approach you use when dealing with 
the events?

P.S. I'm binding the JQuery event to the class attribute that all the elements have. If I was going to bind this to each element based on ID, then this wouldn't be a problem because then I would just use .bind(). By writing this I suddenly though of using .unbind() and then .bind() to link the elements to the events system. What do you think of that? Would you do it in another way?

Thanks in advance.
Kristinn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking to use $.fn.live:

```
$('a').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('im attached even if the DOM has been updated!');
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

Comment: live() doesn't work with everything. If you want to bind a non-supported event with live(), you're out of luck. What I do in this case is put a .bind() call in my reload() function (which I call after an edit, say). This works really well.

Comment: preventDefault() easily can be replaced by return false; 
by the way :)

Comment: I find preventDefault to be much cleaner. return false is reliant on being the last statement in the function body also.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit general, but I have a feeling that what you're looking for is [jquery live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live)

Comment: Yes. jQuery.live() acts in the same way as .bind(), except that it will create new event handlers on elements as they are created.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it just attaches one event handler for the event on the document object and parses the event object to detect which element triggered the event.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.thewebsqueeze.com/tips-and-tricks/tip-for-jquery-live-event.html

http://simpable.com/code/jquery-live-events/

http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/jquery-live-events

http://kylefox.ca/blog/2009/feb/09/live-event-binding-jquery-13/